# How to approval new users in phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I installed my own phabricator and  I`ve configured the username/password authentication method. the authentication method is restricted with email-domains and require the approval of Administrator.

After that, I created a new user account and I can see a notification about People Area and the 'Needs Approval' message but I don´t know where is the action to approval account.

SomeOne knows that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly you need to login as administrator. Then you can find the option "Approval Queue" in Queries part of /people page. You can also go to /people/query/approval/ to see the pending approvals.